# codeigniter adding the IS NULL in the find_in_set

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

while generating the query through **codeigniter** framework

```
$this->db->select('id,memo,sent_to,sent_by,read_by,date')->from('memos')
    ->where("FIND_IN_SET('1',`sent_to`)")->order_by('`id`','DESC')->get();
```

i got an error of adding **IS NULL** in the query automatically

it produce

```
SELECT `id`, `memo`, `sent_to`, `sent_by`, `read_by`, `date` FROM `memos` 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1',`sent_to`) IS NULL ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

instead of

```
SELECT `id`, `memo`, `sent_to`, `sent_by`, `read_by`, `date` FROM `memos` 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1',`sent_to`) ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `!=0` is your `where clause` to remove `IS NULL`

```
$this->db->select('id,memo,sent_to,sent_by,read_by,date')->from('memos')
    ->where("FIND_IN_SET('1',`sent_to`)!=",0)->order_by('`id`','DESC')->get();
```

Comment: Just upgraded to 3.1.2, and I found this problem really annoying. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Below code 100% work.
try it,

```
    $this->db->select('id,memo,sent_to,sent_by,read_by,date');
    $this->db->from('memos');
    $this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET('1',`sent_to`) !=", 0);
    $this->db->order_by('`id`','DESC');
    $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM memos WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1',sent_to) ORDER BY id DESC");
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

> `result_array();` this for return data as objective array

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to write a mysql query for string variable and run it by using 
`$this->db->query('');` instead of using active record.

P/s: Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

`find_in_set()` returns numeric value so thats why we need to use relational operator to evaluate condition 
like

```php
$this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET('x',field_list)>0");
```

Comment: Zaqi Please use proper code format. when you are using code in your post/answer.