# how to give order_by in find_in_set

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

here is my code in that `tool_id` contains values stored as an array and want to get it back the result as stored in table and when I give like this am getting white screen.

```
public function view_tools()
{
    $this->db->select('tu.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) as tool_ids', FALSE);
    $this->db->from('tbl_tools t');
    $this->db->join('tbl_tool_use tu', 'ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(t.id, t.tool_id) desc', 'inner', FALSE);
    $this->db->group_by('tu.id');
    $this->db->order_by('tu.id','desc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390038/codeigniter-adding-the-is-null-in-the-find-in-set) ?

Comment: Enable error reporting and let us you error.

Comment: execute the query and check your query and enable error reporting as well.

Comment: Your query is incorrect. You cannot use `Order By` in `JOIN` and `FIND_IN_SET` in `Order By`. Please try executing a plain query directly into mysql and then convert corrrect query into CI standard.

Comment: sorry  for late replaying here server was down..when i enable error reporting am getting sql syntax error