# FIND_IN_SET add IS NULL automatically in query in codeigniter and also need to add bracket in my query to make group

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, filter

This is how I use FIND_IN_SET in my query, in which it adds IS NULL Automatically in Query and also need to add bracket after WHERE `s`.`cat_id` = '11' AND query

```
$spilt=explode(',',$newstyle);

foreach ($spilt as $splitkey => $splitvalue) {
    if ($splitkey == 0) {
        $this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET(".$splitvalue.",w_card_style)");
    }
    else{
        $this->db->or_where("FIND_IN_SET(".$splitvalue.",w_card_style)");
    }
}
```

When i print the query using `$this->db->last_query()`, it gives query like

```
SELECT `c`.`city_name`, `s`.`name`, `s`.`location`, `s`.`starting_price`, `s`.`budget_range`, `s`.`cat_id`, `s`.`id`, `i`.`path`, `s`.`specification_status`, `s`.`per_unit_charge`, `s`.`w_card_style`, `s`.`w_card_style`, `s`.`budget_range` FROM `image_gallery` as `i` JOIN `specification` as `s` ON `i`.`ser_id`=`s`.`id` JOIN `cities` as `c` ON `c`.`city_id`=`s`.`location` JOIN `wcard_style` as `ws` ON `ws`.`id`=`s`.`w_card_style` WHERE `s`.`cat_id` = '11' AND FIND_IN_SET(1,w_card_style) IS NULL OR FIND_IN_SET(2,w_card_style) IS NULL OR FIND_IN_SET(3,w_card_style) IS NULL AND budget_range BETWEEN 50 AND 100 GROUP BY `ser_id` HAVING `cat_id` = '11' ORDER BY `s`.`budget_range` DESC
```

After each FIND_IN_SET there is IS NULL, So how to remove IS NULL from the Query and also need to add bracket after " WHERE `s`.`cat_id` = '11' AND " at run time like this

```
SELECT `c`.`city_name`, `s`.`name`, `s`.`location`, `s`.`starting_price`, `s`.`budget_range`, `s`.`cat_id`, `s`.`id`, `i`.`path`, `s`.`specification_status`, `s`.`per_unit_charge`, `s`.`w_card_style`, `s`.`w_card_style`, `s`.`budget_range` FROM `image_gallery` as `i` JOIN `specification` as `s` ON `i`.`ser_id`=`s`.`id` JOIN `cities` as `c` ON `c`.`city_id`=`s`.`location` JOIN `wcard_style` as `ws` ON `ws`.`id`=`s`.`w_card_style` WHERE `s`.`cat_id` = '11' AND (FIND_IN_SET(1,w_card_style) IS NULL OR FIND_IN_SET(2,w_card_style) IS NULL OR FIND_IN_SET(3,w_card_style) IS NULL ) AND budget_range BETWEEN 50 AND 100 GROUP BY `ser_id` HAVING `cat_id` = '11' ORDER BY `s`.`budget_range` DESC`enter code here`
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of [codeigniter adding the IS NULL in the find\_in\_set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390038/codeigniter-adding-the-is-null-in-the-find-in-set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code i have modified your code with some chnages.Use my below code it's work.

```
$spilt=explode(',',$newstyle);
          foreach ($spilt as $splitkey => $splitvalue) {
            if ($splitkey == 0) {
            $this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET(".$splitvalue.",w_card_style)!=",0);
            }
            else{
              $this->db->or_where("FIND_IN_SET(".$splitvalue.",w_card_style)!=",0);
            }
          }
```